# Some confusion with pointers in C++ (PPP2 Chapter 17,Exercise 11)

Tags: c++

Exploring C++ with help of Bjarne Stroustrup PPP2, and have stuсk in excercise 11 of 17 Chapter.There i must realize `Link* add(Link* n)` function,where is placing object after, how i can guess its same as `Link* insert(Link* n)` function,where is placing object before.Problem is, my add function is not working properly,like is throwing up `this*` pointer and `prev` pointer have not assigned properly.
My source--->>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Link {
public:
    Link(string n, Link* p = nullptr, Link* s = nullptr) :value{n}, prev{ p }, succ{ s }{};
    string value;
    Link* insert(Link* n);
    Link* add(Link* n);
    Link* erase();
    Link* find(const string& s);
    const Link* find(const  string& s) const;
    Link* advance(int n);
    Link* next() const { return succ;}
    Link* previous() const { return prev; }
private:
    Link* prev;
    Link* succ;
};

Link* Link::insert(Link* n) {
    if (n == nullptr) return this;
    if (this == nullptr) return n;
    n->succ = this;
    if (prev) prev->succ = n;
    n->prev = prev;

    prev = n;
    return n;

}

Link* Link::add(Link* n) {
    if (n == nullptr) return this;
    if (this == nullptr) return n;
    n->prev = this;
    if(succ) succ->prev = n; 
    n->succ = succ;
    succ = n;
    return n;
}



Link* Link::erase() {
    if (this == nullptr) return nullptr;
    if (succ) succ->prev = prev;
    if (prev) prev->succ = succ;
    return succ;
}

Link* Link::find(const  string& s) {
    Link* p=this;
    while (p) {
        if (p->value == s) return p;
        p = next();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

const Link* Link::find(const  string& s) const {
    const Link* p = this;
    while (p) {
        if (p->value == s) { return p; }
        p=p->next();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

Link* Link::advance(int n) {
    Link* p=this;
    if (p == nullptr) return nullptr;
    if (0 < n) {
        while (n--) {
            if (p->succ == nullptr) return nullptr;
            p = p->succ;
        }
    }
    else if (n < 0) {
        while (n++) {
            if (p->prev == nullptr) return nullptr;
            p = p->prev;
        }
    }
    return  p;
}

void print_all(Link* p) {
    cout << "{ ";
    while (p) {
        cout << p->value;
        if (p = p->next())cout << ", ";
        
    }
    cout << " }";
}

    

int main()
{
    Link* norse_gods = new Link{ "Thor"};
    norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link{ "Odin"});
    norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link{ "Loki"});
    norse_gods = norse_gods->insert(new Link{ "Freia" });

    Link* greek_gods = new Link{ "Hera" };
    greek_gods = greek_gods->add(new Link{ "Appolo" });  //There is Appolo is must be placed before "Hera", but is just eat her =)
    greek_gods = greek_gods->insert(new Link{ "Athena"});
    greek_gods = greek_gods->insert(new Link{ "Ares"});
    greek_gods = greek_gods->insert(new Link{ "Poseidon"});


    /*
    
    Link* p = greek_gods->find("Mars");
    if (p) p->value="Ares";

    Link* p2 = norse_gods->find("Zeus");
    if (p2) {
        if (p2 == norse_gods) norse_gods = p2->next();
        p2->erase();
        greek_gods=greek_gods->insert(p2);
    }
    */
    
    print_all(norse_gods);
    cout << "\n";
    print_all(greek_gods);
    cout << "\n";
         
}
```

**My Output--->**

{ Freia, Loki, Odin, Thor }

{ Poseidon, Ares, Athena, Appolo }

Where is created before Hera?

Thanks for attention guys,hope for ur help.

Comment: `if (this == nullptr)` 0_0

Comment: Yep is weird,but this code is from book.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just that you don't print your second list from the beginning since `greek_gods` points out to its second item.

Try:

```
print_all(greek_gods->previous());
```

If you don't understand why, I suggest to use a pen and paper and write down how the list looks like after each update. Or, use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks.But with `print_all(greek_gods->previous())` i have this output. Cant get in mind, why is place Hera to first.
`{ Hera, Poseidon, Ares, Appolo, Athena }`

Comment: @c_thief Because after `add`, `greek_gods` points to `Apollo`. Then, you insert elements in between. It exactly corresponds with the code. Again, use pen and paper and resolve each operation individually.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I purely needed fresh view. When insert works is just moving prev in sequence each time. After bit change `add` function

```
Link* Link::insert(Link* n) {
    if (n == nullptr) return this;
    if (this == nullptr) return n;
    if (prev) {
        n->succ = prev;
        prev->prev = n;
        n->prev = prev->prev;
    }
    else {
        n->succ = this;
        n->prev = prev;
        prev = n;
    }
    return n;
```

For now output is: `{ Poseidon, Ares, Dionis, Athena, Hera, Appolo }`

Thanks!